# Triggering a click event when clicking on bootstrap modal back-ground

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, onclick

I have the following twitter bootstrap modal, I have set the background to static, I can not figure out how to trigger a click event when a user clicks on the background behind the modal.

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="add-stations" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form id="new-station-form" data-companyid="<%= @company.id %>" data-channelid="<%= @channel.id %>" data-channelname="<%= @channel.name %>">
            <div class="modal-header channel-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">INGEST YOUR SELECTED CHANNELS</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <%= render partial: "shared/new_station", locals: { channel_name: @channel.name, stations: @station_unselected }   %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what background? The modal background itself or the background behind the modal?

Comment: the background behind the modal